# Xpath is not working on variable having xml string

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I am facing issue in writing xapth. Let me explain the problem.

I am writing xslt to transform some xml. The xslt also loads one xml file from disk into xslt variable.

**PeopleXml.xml**:

```
   <TestXml>     
     <People>  
       <Person id="MSA1" name="Sachin">
         <Profession>  
           <Role>Developer</Role>
         </Profession>  
       </Person>
       <Person id="ZAG4" name="Rahul">              
         <Profession>  
           <Role>Tester</Role>
          </Profession> 
       </Person>
     </People>  
   </TestXml>
```

**XSLT**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xmlns="http://MyNamespace"  
version="2.0"> 

<xsl:variable name="PeopleXml" select ="document('PeopleXml.xml')"/>

<xsl:variable name="peopleList" select="$PeopleXml/TestXml/People/Person"/>  
<xsl:variable name="person1" select="MSA1"/>  

<xsl:variable name="person" select="$peopleList/Person[@id=$person1]/@name"/>  

<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:value-of select="$person"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Issue**: The xpath "$peopleList/Person[@id=$person1]/@name" is not returning anything. Infact, $peopleList/Person also does not work. However, I can see two person nodes in $peopleList variable when I debugged the code.

Could anyone help me, what I am doing wrong in xpath?

**EDIT**
Above xapth issue has been resolved after applying Daniel's solution. Now, only issue remained is with accessing child nodes of person based on some condition.

Following test does not work.

```
<xsl:variable name="roleDev" select="'Developer'"/>
<xsl:when test="$peopleList/Profession/Role=$roleDev">
   <xsl:value-of select="We have atleast one Developer"/>
</xsl:when>
```

Comment: Could it be issue related to namespace? The PeopleXml.xml does not have any namespace but the xslt has 'xmlns="http://MyNamespace"'.

Comment: For the first xapth issue (where I was trying to compare Ids), the solution provided by Daniel is working. Now, I just want to write xpath which will Check if we have atleast one developer". The xapth I tried is $peopleList/Person/Profession/Role=$roleDev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your problem is here**:

```
<xsl:variable name="person1" select="MSA1"/>
```

**This results in having the `$person1` variable *empty*.
Why?**

Because the *expression* `MSA1` is evaluated -- the current node doesn't have any children named "MSA1" and nothing is selected.

**Solution**:

Specify the wanted string as string literal:

```
<xsl:variable name="person1" select="'MSA1'"/>
```

---

**Your Second Question**:

> Now, only issue remained is with accessing child nodes of person based
>   on some condition.

**Use**:

```
boolean($peopleList[Profession/Role = 'Developer'])
```

This produces `true()` exactly when there is a node in `$peopleList` such that it has at least one `Profession/Role` crand-child whose string value is the string `"Developer"`

Answer (score 2):

Since the variable `peopleList` is already `Person` nodes, you should access them like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="person" select="$peopleList[@id=$person1]/@name"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. It worked! However, if i have to access any element inside person (e.g. Role), then its giving problem. I have updated the xml and xpath in question. Any suggestion?